# Split data in a CSV file based on column headers / row headers using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, split

I have CSV data as shown below:

[image: data]

Since few headers are coming in between, I wanted to split this data and have one sheet for input and one sheet for output.

Comment: If you want to modify a csv, post the real csv data as text not an unrelevant excel picture. I'm missing the desired outcome and also you own try to code this. [SO] isn't a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data=import-csv -path "file.csv"
$data_length =$data.count()
for ($k= 0; $K -le $data_length; $k++)
{
  $data_type =($data['outlet P'].gettype).Name
  if($data_type -eq 'string')
  {
$new_sheet.add($data['outlet P'])
}
}
```

## try to count the number of times the condition occurs.depending on that "$new_sheet_1", "$new_sheet_2","$new_sheet_3" can be defined.